# Cloud Run: Connecting to a CloudSQL database on another GCP Project

Tags: google-cloud-platform, permissions, google-cloud-sql, google-cloud-run

I am having trouble connecting my [Project A] Cloud Run instance to a [Project B] Cloud SQL instance.

I already set up the service account permissions as told on this article: https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/connect-run

Which are like this:

- I created a service account on [Project B] that has Cloud SQL Admin and Cloud SQL Client permissions.
- I created a service account on [Project A] for the Cloud Run instance, this account has a user role on the service account for [Project B]

Both projects have the Cloud SQL Admin API active, and if I build the same Cloud Run instance on [Project B] it connects without any hitches, so I imagine this is a permission issue.

The error I get on the logs from [Project A] Cloud Run is: *googleapi: Error 403: The client is not authorized to make this request., notAuthorized*

Comment: I don't get this at all `this account has a user role on the service account for [Project B]` Can you clarify this?

Comment: The service account for the cloud run instance has a _Service Account User_ permission on the cloud sql service account, I imagine this is how you link both of them

Comment: Actually not, the Service Account created in [Project A] should have Cloud SQL user role in [Project B] unless you want to impersonalize the SA from project B using the one in Project A. If you want to impersonalize can you show the code you're using for this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I replicated your error and managed to fix it without creating a `Service Account` manually on **project A (Cloud Run)** and  **project B(Cloud SQL)**.

When you deploy a **service** in `Cloud Run`, it uses the [default Compute Engine service account](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/configuring/service-accounts) which is like this: **project-number-compute@developer.gserviceaccount.com**.

Then I open the **Cloud IAM** page on **project B** where the **Cloud SQL** is located then I grant the role of Service Account from **Project A (Cloud run)** with a `Cloud SQL Client` or `Cloud SQL Admin` permission.

Sample screenshot of **Project B Cloud IAM Page** where I grant the **project-number-compute@developer.gserviceaccount.com** service account from `Cloud Run`:
[image]

You can also see what Service Account your Cloud run uses in **revisions tab  ->  Security tab**

[image]

Comment: Thanks so much!!, that fixed the problem. I thought I needed a service account and couldn't do it directly on the IAM page.